# submit partial changes to datacontext

Tags: linq-to-sql

is there a way to insert an entity without using the SubmitChanges() function of the datacontext? I want to do this because I have other changes done on my datacontext which I do not want to submit yet, if I call the SubmitChanges function it will submit all changes including the ones I do not want to save yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use the new **DataContext instance** as it is a light-weight
OR
Use the **InsertOnSubmit** method for those entities you want to add. Than calling the *SubmitChanges* only update desired entities.